# How do I ignore empty tags when I'm using regexps?

Tags: regex

What should I include in my regexps in order to allow it to ignore empty tags?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that you require at least 1 character in between the quotes:

So something like this:

```
(title|alt)="(.+)"
```